# A question about Confidence Interval

Tags: confidence-interval

Recently, I have some trouble with confidence interval. The specific question is as follows:

Assuming that the return of an asset$(P_t)$ conforms to a normal distribution, if the average return$(\bar{x})$ and sample variance of the asset $(s^2)$are obtained through data collection, how to construct the confidence interval of the log return$(\ln \frac{P_t}{P_{t-1}})$?

Since the form of log return looks like a t(1) distribution under the normalization, my idea is to find the similar estimator to estimate. However, I can't manage to find it. Can anyone help me solve this question? Thank you.

Comment: I didn't know what "return of asset" means. However, a Google search shows that it may be positive or negative. So, for some $t$ , we may have $\frac{P_t}{P_{t−1}}$ to be negative, right ? In that case, how will you write its $\log$ ? Please clarify a bit.